# How to convert ARPlaneAnchor to 2d line (parallel projection)

Tags: ios, arkit, scnnode, aranchor

I use `ARKit` to scan vertical planes in `ARSCNView`. I'd like to draw them later on as 2d lines (parallel projection from above). `ARPlaneAnchor` doesn't have start and end points, but only center point and width (`ARPlaneAnchor.extent`).

I also tried with `SCNNode` and its `boundingBox` object but the direct coordinates there were different than scanned planes.

How can I convert `ARPlaneAnchor` or `SCNNode` to 2d line (2d coordiantes)?

Comment: You could use the superclass property ´ARAnchor.transform´ to obtain the orientation of the plane. Then, given the center coordinate, the width of the plane and the orientation you should be able to find the 2D start and end point of the line

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the center point and height/width to calculate the estimated plane edge positions and go from there. Just note that `center` is relative to the plane's anchor.

Assuming your plane is vertical as you note, something like this should get you started:

```
    let centerLocal = verticalPlane.center
    let centerWorld = centerLocal + verticalPlane.transform.translation
    let extents = verticalPlane.extent
    let upperLeft = centerWorld + SIMD3<Float>(-extents.x / 2, 0, extents.z / 2)
    let bottomRight = centerWorld + SIMD3<Float>(extents.x / 2, 0, -extents.z / 2)
```

Extension I used:

```
extension float4x4 {
    // Treats matrix as a transform matrix and grabs the 
    // translation component of the transform.       
    var translation: SIMD3<Float> {
        let translation = columns.3
        return SIMD3<Float>(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
    }
}
```